# Limitations on file append when using in multi-processed environment

Tags: multiprocessing, fopen, file-locking

My process creates a log file and appends a new line at the end of the file by using `a`, e.g:

```
fopen("log.txt", "a");
```

The order of the writes is not critical, but I need to ensure that `fopen` always succeeds. My question is, can the call above be executed from multiple processes at the same time on Windows, Linux and macOS without any race-condition?

If not, what is the most common and easy way to ensure I can write to the log file? There is file-lokcing, but also a file-lock (aka log.txt.lock) possible. Could anyone share some insights or resources which go more into detail?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use any synchronization between processes, you'll highly likely have moment when several processes will try to write to the file and the best you can get is mesh of input strings.

In order to synchronize any work in several processes (`multiprocessing` module). Use `Lock`. It will prevent several processes to do some work simultaneously.

It will look something like this:

```py
import multiprocessing

# create lock in main process and "send" it to child processes.
lock = multiprocessing.Lock() 

# ...
# in child Process
with lock:
    do_some_work()
```

If you need more detailed example, feel free to ask.

Also you can check example in [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I also thought of a lock, but the processes are run independently in the Terminal

Comment: @HelloWorld if you have several independent processes, you can try to use message queue like RabbitMQ or something lighter. Message queue guarantees that log will be written on disk, and tasks will be written in the order they come to the queue (if no priorities) Or you can do something yours based on sockets - one process will be "logfile writer" other processes will be sending data to the process via sockets.

Comment: Unfortunately, my project is not a Python project, I will see what I can do in other frameworks. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @HelloWorld if your project in PHP (sorry if I am wrong, just googled `fopen` function) you can still use RabbitMQ https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html It is good production level service if you have many independent processes/microservices to interact with one another.

Comment: Thanks for looking it up, but `fopen` is very standard and used almost everywhere, from `C`, to `C++` to `PHP`, to `Python`, `Fortran`... In my case it is a C++ project and unfortunately this approach does not work. There must be a non-IPC solution